# Raster and polygon layer at different location

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon

I´m new to QGIS and have a problem with overlaying two layers. The first one is a map of all municipalities in Germany (shapefile) and the second one is a gridded annual sum of incoming direct radiation on the horizontal plane for Germany (asc. file).

Both have the same Layer CRS (the same as the global one) but they are not overlaying.

It looks like the Y coordinates are matching but the X ones are not. All shapefiles I´ll add are matching with the municipality (shp) map, only this raster one is not working. I already converted it to a polygon, but this does not change anything. I added a screenshot. I tried a lot of things I found online but nothing changes the position. How can I line them up so I can perform some overlay analysis?

I use QGIS version 3.18.2-Zürich

The asc. file can be downloaded over here: [german weather service data bank](https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/annual/radiation_direct/)
I used the "grids_germany_annual_radiation_direct_2016.zip" file.

I opened it with a text editor to delete the descreption up to
"NCOLS 654
NROWS 866" (otherwise the file can´t be opened with qgis).

As soon as I opened it in QGIS, the Layer CRS was already set up, or at least it seemed that way. I also uploaded a screenshot from that.

[image: QGIS screenshot with both layers]
[image: CRS selector of asc. file]

Comment: Can you share the ascii file for testing?

Comment: Add a screenshot of the SHP and Raster showing the CRS info, was the ASCII had the same CRS as the SHP already?

Comment: I uploaded the file to the original file. The ASCII had the same CRS as the SHP.

Comment: I posted an answer that resolves the problem witch the ASCII file. For the shapefile, you did not provide any data, so can't say if that is wrong, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that you deleted the header of the file. That's why it doesn't work because the header includes the CRS definition: `Koordinatensystem=Gauss-Krueger 3. Meridianstreifen Potsdam-Datum`. This corresponds to `EPSG:31467` (as is stated in the documentation to the data, to be found on the site you linked to).

What you have to do: `right-click your layer / Layer CRS / Set layer CRS` and select `EPSG:31467`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works

Answer (score 1):

Did you alter the projection of the raster at all?  The CRS is defined as one thing but the actual projection should be something else.  The most common cause of this is someone defining a projection rather than reprojecting a layer.  I would check your workflow to make sure you didn't inadvertently re-define the projection.  If so, the easiest solution is to re-define it once you establish what it should be, or just download it again.

Comment: Simply put, the CRS is probably not defined correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I gave some more details in my original post.